# How to create a subcategory in a category using generics.CreateAPIView?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a subcategory under my category. This is my views.py

```
class CreateSubCategoryViews(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubCategorySerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

My urls.py

```
path('category/<slug:slug>/create/', views.CreateSubCategoryViews.as_view(), name='create-subcategory-views'),
```

My models.py

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'SubCategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are Dealing with hierarchical data then You can use [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

in Models.py

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel
from mptt.managers import TreeManager
class category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent =  models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='child')

    objects = TreeManager()

    class MPTTMeta:
        level_attr = 'mptt_level'
        order_insertion_by=['name']
```

in Views.py

```
class CategoryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = categoryTreeSerializer
```

in Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField
class CategoryTreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    child = RecursiveField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id', 'name','slug','parent', 'child',)
```